# Transform a string from "abc" -> "^A.*B.*C" in Bash

Tags: bash, shell

I'm calling a bash-script like `./test.sh abc` and the argument `"abc"` is used for a grep argument in the form `^char_1.*char_2.* ... char_N`, where "char_i" is the capitalized version of the i'th input character. The current text file I'm grep'ing is a long list of fully-capitalized words, one on each newline.

In reading about string manipulation I come upon a plethora of highly confounding examples from programs like sed, awk, tr, and others.  If my goal is simply to capitalize the input chars and place them in that form, which Bash command is most useful and how could I achieve this manipulation with that commmand?

Comment: Err, `^A.*B.*C` or `^a.*b.*c`? I'm *presuming* that that difference isn't actually intended, since it isn't reflected in explanatory text but only in the title, but explicit clarification wouldn't hurt.

Comment: sorry, that was ambiguous .  i edited it for clarity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One simple implementation that uses **only** bash's built-in string manipulation support:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#              ^^^^- NOT /bin/sh; the C-style for loop is an extension.

in=${1^^}
out='^'

for ((i=0; i<${#in}; i++)); do
  out+="${in:$i:1}.*"
done
out=${out%".*"} # trim last .*

echo "$out"
```

See [BashFAQ #100](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100) ("How do I do string manipulations in bash?") for a full description of native string manipulation operations. The ones used above are:

- `${var^^}` expands to an all-uppercase version of the contents of `var` (note that this requires bash 4; for older versions, `in=$(tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]' <<<"$1")` is the more traditional approach).
- `${#in}` expands to the length of the string present in the variable named `in`.
- `${varname:start:len}` expands to the substring of the variable named `varname`, starting at the 0-indexed position `start` and proceeding for `len` characters.
- `${out%".*"}` expands to the contents of `$out`, but with the literal string `.*` trimmed from the end. (If it weren't for the inner quotes, `.*` would be treated as a pattern, so we'd remove everything after the last `.` in the literal string, were one present).

The above are also all *parameter expansions*; they're described in detail at http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe.

Comment: thanks, this is super helpful.  `echo $BASH_VERSION` logs `3.2.57(1)-release` so i went with the `tr` command for capitalization.

Comment: Alternatively, on `bash` v4, `declare -u out` will convert any characters assigned to it into uppercase.

Answer (score 0):

Little verbose but awk can also do the job:

```
s='abc'

awk '{s=toupper($0); c1=substr(s,1,1); s=substr(s,2); gsub(/./, ".*&", s); print "^" c1 s}' <<< "$s"

^A.*B.*C
```

- First we covert to uppercase using `toupper` function.
- We use `substr` function to break input into 2 parts i.e. first character and rest
- For rest part we insert `.*` before each character in `gsub` function
- Finally we concatenate and get the desired format

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, here's a `sed` solution:

```
sed 's/./\U&.*/g; s/^/^/; s/\.\*$//' <<<abc
^A.*B.*C
```

This is actually pretty straightforward:

- `s/./\U&.*/g` - replace every character (`.`) with an uppercase version of itself (`\U&`) followed by `.*`;
- replace the beginning of the string (`^`) with an actual `^`;
- replace the literal `.*` at the end of the line (`\.\*$`) with an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Another **pure** `bash` using regexes:

```
[[ "${1^^}" =~ ${1//?/(.)} ]]    # to upprcase + make regex + match
b=${BASH_REMATCH[@]:1}           # join by spaces
printf -v out "^%s" "${b// /.*}" # print to var, prepend ^, replace spaces with .*

echo "$out"
#^A.*B.*C
```

and also pfe (perl for everything) :)

```
perl -F// -nlE 'say uc("^".join(".*",@F))' <<< "$1"
#^A.*B.*C
```

Comment: @alvits yikes!. First me playing with a function and `IFS` and when dropped the idea the `$()` remains. Youre right ofc. :) - edited & thanx!